# SQL: finding duplicates that do not have a success message

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling to return all batch_id's that do not contain a corresponding "PASS"

```
+--------------------------------------+
| ID         Batch_ID          STATUS  |
+--------------------------------------+
| 1          100               PENDING |
| 2          100               PENDING |
| 3          100               PASS    | < 100 has passed
| 4          101               PENDING |
| 5          101               PASS    | < 101 has passed
| 6          103               PENDING |
| 7          103               PASS    | < 103 has passed
| 8          104               PENDING |
| 9          104               PENDING |
| 10         104               PENDING | < i want to return this because 104 does not contain a "PASS"
| 11         105               PENDING |
| 12         105               PASS    | < 105 has passed
| etc..                                |
+--------------------------------------+
```

From the above table, i need an sql statement that only returns batch_id 104 because it never had a status of "PASS"

The database is an oracle DB, therefore if its is not possible with a simple select statement a PL/SQL could be used. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all batches that are pending, and among those filter out the one's that have once passed. One solution could be:

```
select id, batch_id, status from table t
where t.status = 'PENDING'
and NOT EXISTS (select 'X' from table t2 where t.batch_id = t2.batch_id and t2.status = 'PASS');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select batch_id
from t
group by batch_id
having sum(case when status = 'PASS' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! it worked perfectly. I have been trying to get this work for hours

Comment: @paul24682 . . . I'm surprised that you didn't accept this answer which (1) does not produce duplicates and (2) was almost 10 minutes earlier than the other answer.